# Set bucket in GCS Proxy

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform

I am using https://github.com/mike-sirs/gcsproxy as a proxy running on a compute instance allowing curl access to objects in a private GCS bucket.

I can build the dockerfile and curl with http://127.0.0.1:8080/BUCKET_NAME/Object, but the legacy app that I need to connect this to cannot pass the BUCKET_NAME.

I am trying to figure out how to either pass the bucket name as a variable, or even just hard code it for the time being.

I've tried updating cmd/gcsproxy/main.go but with no luck.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Looking at the source seen here:

https://github.com/mike-sirs/gcsproxy/blob/master/cmd/gcsproxy/main.go#L105

It appears that references to `params["bucket"]` is where the bucket name is coming from.  If you wanted to hard code, this looks like the place.

Comment: That worked @Kolban! I updated:

```
 if *useDomainName {
  params["bucket"] = r.Host
 }
```

to


``` if *useDomainName {
  params["bucket"] = "BUCKET_NAME"
 }
```

And updated:


`useDomainName = flag.Bool("dn", false, "Use hostname as a bucket name.")`

to

`useDomainName = flag.Bool("dn", true, "Use hostname as a bucket name.")`

to have the useDomainName flag be true by default.

Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the help from @Kolban I was able to get this working.

I updated:

```
    if *useDomainName {
        params["bucket"] = r.Host
    }
```

to

```
    if *useDomainName {
        params["bucket"] = "BUCKET_NAME"
    }
```

And updated:

`useDomainName = flag.Bool("dn", false, "Use hostname as a bucket name.")`

to

`useDomainName = flag.Bool("dn", true, "Use hostname as a bucket name.")`

to have the useDomainName flag be true by default.